# В каких случаях "Е" после согласной не смягчает её, и читается как "Э"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

По правилам русского языка, **е** после согласной должна смягчать это согласную.

Например - Например [напримьэр]

Но есть случаи, лично для меня очень спорные, в которых она не смягчает согласную и читается просто как **э**. Лично я стараюсь в таких случаях использовать букву э, чтобы не вводить читателя в заблуждение или давать ему повода читать слово так, как ему удобнее, если мне - как автору - важно, чтобы произношение было таким, как задумано.

Примеры таких случаев в основном имена иностранного происхождения.
Например Рей [рэй], Грей [грэй], Реймонд [рэймонд], Мег [мэг].
Но, хотя я сейчас на-вскидку и не могу вспомнить, в русских (по моему разумению) словах - не именах, хоть редко, но такие "исключения" также встречаются.

Есть ли какое-либо правило по поводу двойных стандартов произношения ? Или же это двойные стандарты написания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**О двойных стандартах (история буквы Э)**

Буква Э (так называемое «Э оборотное») –  **сравнительно «молодая» буква в русском алфавите:** она появилась лишь в XVIII веке, вскоре после установления гражданской азбуки, при этом, по сравнению с буквой Е, она стала обозначать чистый, нейотированный звук.  Первоначальное назначение Э – употребление в начале слова или корня слова (этот, эх, поэтому), после гласных в заимствованных словах (поэт) и в иноязычных собственных именах (Эдисон, Суэц).   Несмотря на неприятие этой буквы некоторыми писателями и учеными, она не только закрепилась в русской графике, но и стала писаться после согласных в иноязычных словах (мэр).

**В то же время буква Э так и осталась буквой с ограниченными возможностями,** так как в большинстве случаев для обозначения звука Э после согласных ее заменяет буква Е, и здесь изменить ситуацию вряд ли удастся. А почему?

**В исконно русских словах** звук Э употребляется только после мягких согласных и обозначается буквой Е.  Твердое произношение гласного Э характерно только **для заимствованных слов**, с чем и связано ограничение возможностей буквы Э. Заимствованное  слово в языке в начальный период обычно произносится с твердым Э и как бы примеряет для себя письменную форму Э или Е. **Окончательный  выбор  зависит от многих причин (фонетических и графических).**

В некоторых случаях (достаточно редко) **письменная форма Э закрепляется** в языке (как и твердое произношение), в других – пишется только  Е, а произношение гласного может меняться от твердого к мягкому. **В заключение делается и этот выбор – слово окончательно вписывается в фонетическую и графическую систему языка.** Именно подобные колебания  при выборе фонетической формы заимствованных слов не позволяет навести строгий порядок в написании букв Э и Е, а также  в произношении соответствующих им звуков.

Comment: Спасибо за понятный развернутый комментарий, но остается вопрос - является ли ошибкой писать э в тех случаях, где она читается как э, но вроде как статистически принято писать е?

Comment: Письменная форма слова закрепляется в словаре и является единственно правильной. Если слово совсем новое и в словарях его нет, то, я думаю,  придется воспользоваться статистикой его употребления в письменных текстах (ориентироваться на произношение сложно).

Answer (score 4):

В словах иноязычного происхождения, пишущихся с буквой е, предшествующий согласный может произноситься твердо. Так, после букв, передающих мягкий согласный, буква е пишется в словах асбест, версия, гетто, деспот, зебра, комета, леди, пионер, абонент, аспект, акварель, сектор, патент, дефект и в ряде других. После букв, передающих твердый согласный, е пишется в словах беби, денди, дельта, модель, экзема, кузен, сленг, бизнесмен, инерция, фонетика, капелла, регби, рейтинг, диспансер, сеттер, коттедж, партер, стенд, темп и многих других, а также в несклоняемых нарицательных словах, последовательно пишущихся с конечной буквой е, напр.: безе, шимпанзе, макраме, резюме, пенсне, турне, купе, гофре, пюре, тире, кабаре, фрикасе, шоссе, эссе, варьете, декольте, карате, кафе, и в словах с иноязычным суффиксом -есса (типа поэтесса, стюардесса, баронесса); в ряде собственных имен, напр.: Кармен, Неру, Рерих, Врем, Дантес, Тейлор, Дельфы, Сен-Готард.

[См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=12#pp12)